# Merge multiple file text without delete the first line of each file in R

Tags: r, merge

I want to merge 100 files text that I have put in a folder. Each file is like that:

```
0                           
0.72902 0                       
0.45426 0.54525 0                   
0.16167 0.34908 0.22247 0               
0.52886 0.54775 0.18069 0.28457 0           
0.93595 0.15927 0.8284  0.50287 0.82813 0       
0.25058 0.48914 0.13144 0.07898 0.16315 0.72607 0   
0.09604 0.80318 0.63657 0.27424 0.69319 0.91529 0.43121 0
```

I used this command for merging several files text, suggested by a blog.

```
setwd("target_dir/")

file_list <- list.files()

for (file in file_list){

  # if the merged dataset doesn't exist, create it
  if (!exists("dataset")){
    dataset <- read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
  }

  # if the merged dataset does exist, append to it
  if (exists("dataset")){
    temp_dataset <-read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
    dataset<-rbind(dataset, temp_dataset)
    rm(temp_dataset)
  }

}
```

The problem is that applying this command I obtain all files merged together, BUT without the first line of each file (in  my case the first zero of the first column). While I would keep it.
In addition I would like that each file text in the dataframe is divided by a blank line from the following text file.

Any idea on how to solve the problem?

Comment: A first step might be to set `header=FALSE`, as now your first zero is considered the header. Can you elaborate why you want a blank line?

Comment: Heroka, doing header=FALSE I obtain what I wanted. Perfect. I need the blank line because i'm bulding an input file text to read by a software. This software require that each matrix is separated from the following by a blank line. Do you any idea on how i can add a blank line each 8 rows?

Comment: I think the answer given by u/bgoldst shows how to add a blank (or line-consisting-of-NA's) line to your dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setwd('target_dir/');
file_list <- list.files();
dataset <- data.frame(); ## initialize dataset to an empty data.frame
for (file in file_list) dataset <- rbind(if (nrow(dataset) > 0) rbind(dataset,NA),read.table(file,sep='\t',fill=T));
dataset;
##         V1      V2      V3      V4      V5      V6      V7 V8
## 1  0.00000      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA
## 2  0.72902 0.00000      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA
## 3  0.45426 0.54525 0.00000      NA      NA      NA      NA NA
## 4  0.16167 0.34908 0.22247 0.00000      NA      NA      NA NA
## 5  0.52886 0.54775 0.18069 0.28457 0.00000      NA      NA NA
## 6  0.93595 0.15927 0.82840 0.50287 0.82813 0.00000      NA NA
## 7  0.25058 0.48914 0.13144 0.07898 0.16315 0.72607 0.00000 NA
## 8  0.09604 0.80318 0.63657 0.27424 0.69319 0.91529 0.43121  0
## 9       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA
## 10 0.00000      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA
## 11 0.49272 0.00000      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA
## 12 0.94009 0.89679 0.00000      NA      NA      NA      NA NA
## 13 0.20863 0.86001 0.98594 0.00000      NA      NA      NA NA
## 14 0.11592 0.23149 0.60292 0.35263 0.00000      NA      NA NA
## 15 0.16404 0.81930 0.01534 0.41006 0.39640 0.00000      NA NA
## 16 0.38128 0.82583 0.18072 0.39924 0.73311 0.84009 0.00000 NA
## 17 0.91172 0.41074 0.83599 0.49375 0.74877 0.16469 0.78046  0
```

Comment: Ok this correct, but my final result actually is a dataframe with, first all the matrices not separated by the blank line and then there is the dataframe with the same matrices but separated by the blank line.

Comment: I don't understand. Did you run the code including the `if (exists('dataset')) rm(dataset)` line?

Comment: Yes, I run exactly and exclusively the code that you proposed.

Comment: And the result you got had duplication of the input file content?

Comment: Yes.  This is what I run.                                                                                                file_list <- list.files()
 if (exists('dataset')) rm(dataset) ## ensure dataset does not exist when entering the loop
for (file in file_list) dataset <- rbind(if (exists('dataset')) rbind(dataset,NA),read.table(file,sep='\t',fill=T))
> write.table(dataset, "barrier_file2.txt", quote=FALSE, sep="\t", na = "", row.names=FALSE, col.name=FALSE)

Comment: Hmm. Are you running that code from inside a function? One theory I have is that the `rm()` might only be working on a function-local `dataset`, but then the `for` loop picks up a `dataset` at a higher scope, such as global scope. Please try my edited code and let me know if it works.

Comment: bgoldst, sorry was a file text (ho9lding the matrices without blank lines) present in the same folder of the files text to merge. This is why I had this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to merge files there is no reason to parse tables or use rbind. Something like this should be just enough:

```
merge_files <- function(file_list, file) {
    invisible(lapply(
        file_list,
        function(f) cat(readLines(f), "", file=file, sep='\n', append=TRUE)
    ))
}
```

Using system tools like `cat` should be much faster but less portable.